# Azure SQL ddl build fail in pipeline - ignore sys.tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

Our build is failing for our Azure SQL DDL (dacpac creation) due to a new view referencing sys.tables and child objects -

These are deployed and exist in our Azure SQL environment, but are not included in the source code ddl - is there a flag/option I can implement on the Azure build pipeline to ignore sys.tables and all child object references during the build process?

### [error]DDL\Reporting\Views\vw_ArchiveTables.sql(16,6): Error SQL71501: View: [Reporting].[vw_ArchiveTables] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[tables].

6-f51e-57a1-6dd4-575fd75fc7ef&l=47

Comment: The answer is just a google away https://the.agilesql.club/2017/11/ssdt-how-to-fix-error-sql17502/

Comment: If you answer has been resolved, could you please post your answer?